# How to pass header values in web api using HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, dotnet-httpclient

I'm new to ASP.NET Web API 2. I'm trying to access a third party API, so to access it first I need to pass a authorization Token in the header with the API URL. I'm able to access the data with Postman but I'm unable to do it with Code.

Following is my code, I'm not sure if I'm going in the right direction. Any help would be appreciated.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("Url");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Token "+ "MyToken");
    var re = Request;
    var headers = re.Headers;

     if (headers.Contains("Token"))
     {
         string token = headers.GetValues("Token").First();
     }

     return null;

 }
```

Comment: Show the (sanitized) raw request that works with post man

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If setting the default authorization header of the `HttpClient` for all its requests use a `AuthenticationHeaderValue` set on the `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization`

like in the following example...

```cs
//...other code removed for brevity

var tokenType = "Token"; //Other APIs use Bearer or other auth types.
var token = "MyToken";
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(tokenType, token);

//...other code removed for brevity.
```

Any requests made using the client will have an authorization header

```
Authorization Token MyToken
```